# How can I use wildcards within Apple Mail rules?

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I have a couple dozen rules within Apple Mail and some have hundreds of lines.  The latter are rules mostly to divert spam.  I own several domain names and get endless spam to made-up or altered usernames on those domains.

I have no problem with fake usernames that end up on spammers' lists.  I can easily add them to one of my "junk" rules.

```
any recipient contains dan@mydomain.com
any recipient contains jose@mydomain.com
any recipient contains marydoe@myotherdomain.com
any recipient ends with smith@myotherdomain.com
```

The problem comes with more randomly generated names.  For example, I discovered 3-4 fake usernames that start with "Anne."  Ditto for multiple common names.  Plus tons with numbers that start with the letter "x."  These aren't just variations; they're autogenerated and I see new ones regularly.

No problem, for usernames I know I don't use, I can just set up lines that contain:

```
x*@mydomain.com
ann*@mydomain.com
z*@myotherdomain.com
```

Except Apple Mail does not allow the use of wildcards in rules.  Not * or ?.

I don't want to stop all mail that goes to an email that begins with "anne," for example.  Because that will divert all mail that goes to my friend annelastname@domain-I-don't-own, including those sent to her as part of a group.  Since it's not just one friend Anne but rather multiple ones, plus countless usernames that might start with "x" or "z" and so forth, whitelisting won't work.  I must be able to put in my domain name as part of the rule.

I also don't want to create a separate rule for every instance.  One where it meets the requirements of "contains username" **and** "contains domain name."  Why?  Because I'd need hundreds of them.  I just want to add a new username set as a line in an existing rule.

Nor do I want to take the nuclear approach and change my domain name's settings at my ISP to junk every username I haven't specified (it's a pain to log in every time I whitelist a new username too).  I already divert catch-all email to a "misc" account but I still have to go through it.  I want to be able to identify selected username patterns as probably spam.

While a better anti-spam program would be nice, it's not what I'm asking about and I still need a direct answer to my question even if I had a better spam filter.

I'm open to Apple Scripts, though I don't yet know how to use it and don't know if it will work here.

**How can I achieve the equivalent of using wildcards within Apple Mail?**